# How to create new db instance based on trigger caused by insertion of record in a particular DB's table? (Any DB)

Tags: nosql, rdbms

Looking for solutions in any database? Relational or NOSql

Example,

```
DB Name -> administration
Table Name -> Students

Record Inserted ->
   Name -> Kramer
   Roll -> 1

New DB Created -> `student_kramer_1`
```